# Delphi executable version returns always the same value

Tags: delphi

I am trying to get the version of my running executable so I know when my application has changed to a new version with new features.

I am using the following code to get the version:

```
function GetVersaoExe: string;
type
   PFFI = ^vs_FixedFileInfo;
var
   F : PFFI;
   Handle : Dword;
   Len : Longint;
   Data : Pchar;
   Buffer : Pointer;
   Tamanho : Dword;
   Parquivo: Pchar;
   Arquivo : string;
begin
   Arquivo := Application.ExeName;
   Parquivo := StrAlloc(Length(Arquivo) + 1);
   StrPcopy(Parquivo, Arquivo);
   Len := GetFileVersionInfoSize(Parquivo, Handle);
   ShowMessage(IntToStr(Len));
   Result := '';
   if Len > 0 then
   begin
      Data:=StrAlloc(Len+1);
      if GetFileVersionInfo(Parquivo,Handle,Len,Data) then
      begin
         VerQueryValue(Data, '\',Buffer,Tamanho);
         F := PFFI(Buffer);
         Result := Format('%d.%d.%d.%d',
         [HiWord(F^.dwFileVersionMs),
         LoWord(F^.dwFileVersionMs),
         HiWord(F^.dwFileVersionLs),
         Loword(F^.dwFileVersionLs)]
         );
      end;
      StrDispose(Data);
   end;
   StrDispose(Parquivo);
end;
```

This returns me the number **4.0.1.1**.

The problem is that I've been using this function for a while and it never changes this number, it is always **4.0.1.1**, I need a number that will change each time I rebuild the application to know that something has changed since the last build.

I checked about three other ways to get the version number and they all happen to do the same
thing.

There is a [similiar question on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180066/how-do-i-get-the-version-number-of-the-current-project-using-toolsapi-in-delphi) but I still don't know if it works. I checked this question and tried to use their way but there is another problem. When I import `ToolsAPI` in my uses unit to use `IOTAProjectOptionsConfigurations` and gives me the following error: `Cannot compile unit ToolsAPI`.

At last I tried to solve this last problem but I couldn't.

Comment: It's your job to set the version. How are you doing that at the moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply configure your project to auto-increment the version number on each new build.  The [Version Info](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Version_Info) page in the Project Options has a checkbox for that purpose.

---

That said, in the code you showed, you don't need to use `StrAlloc()`/`StrDispose()` at all. Simply pass `PChar(Arquivo)` as input to `GetFileVersionInfoSize()` and `GetFileVersionInfo()`, and change `Data` to an `array of Byte` (or `TBytes` if your version of Delphi has it) using `SetLength()` to allocate it and letting the compiler deallocate it automatically.

```pascal
function GetVersao(const Arquivo: String): string;
type
  PFFI = ^vs_FixedFileInfo;
var
  F : PFFI;
  Handle : Dword;
  Len : Longint;
  Data : array of Byte; // or TBytes
  Buffer : Pointer;
  Tamanho : Dword;
begin
  Result := '';
  Len := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(Arquivo), Handle);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Len));
  if Len > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Data, Len);
    if GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(Arquivo), Handle, Len, PByte(Data)) then
    begin
      if VerQueryValue(PByte(Data), '\', Buffer, Tamanho) then
      begin
        F := PFFI(Buffer);
        Result := Format('%d.%d.%d.%d',
          [HiWord(F^.dwFileVersionMs),
          LoWord(F^.dwFileVersionMs),
          HiWord(F^.dwFileVersionLs),
          Loword(F^.dwFileVersionLs)]
        );
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetVersaoExe: string;
begin
  Result := GetVersao(Application.ExeName);
end;
```

If you really want to be slick, you don't even need to use `GetFileVersionInfo/Size()` at all.  You can use `(Find|Load|Lock)Resource()` to access the calling process's `RT_VERSION` resource directly instead:

```pascal
function GetVersao(Module: THandle): string;
type
  PFFI = ^vs_FixedFileInfo;
var
  F : PFFI;
  Len : Longint;
  Data : array of Byte; // or TBytes
  Buffer : Pointer;
  Tamanho : Dword;
  hRes, hResData: THandle;
begin
  Result := '';
  hRes := FindResource(Module, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), RT_VERSION);
  Len := SizeOfResource(hRes);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Len));
  if Len > 0 then
  begin
    hResData := LoadResource(Module, hRes);
    Buffer := LockResource(hResData);
    SetLength(Data, Len);
    Move(Buffer^, Data[0], Len);
    if VerQueryValue(PByte(Data), '\', Buffer, Tamanho) then
    begin
      F := PFFI(Buffer);
      Result := Format('%d.%d.%d.%d',
        [HiWord(F^.dwFileVersionMs),
        LoWord(F^.dwFileVersionMs),
        HiWord(F^.dwFileVersionLs),
        Loword(F^.dwFileVersionLs)]
      );
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetVersaoExe: string;
begin
  Result := GetVersao(GetModuleHandle(nil));
end;
```